# Is it possible to change the default font of VS Code editor to source code pro font?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

The default fonts of VS Code editor are:
Monaco
Menlo
Consolas
"Droid Sans Mono"
"Inconsolata"
"Courier New"
monospace.

But I want to add source code pro font.
I tried

```
{"editor.fontFamily": "SourceCodePro-Regular"}
```

I have that font in my "fonts" "(Windows).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install all Fonts from this [ZIP](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/archive/refs/tags/2.042R-u/1.062R-i/1.026R-vf.zip).
Try this in user settings JSON file

```
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "Source Code Pro"
}
```

Save it then Restart VS Code.

Comment: The link is invalid. Check https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases.

Answer (score 5):

There should be an ending double quote after the font name:

```
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "SourceCodePro-Regular"
}
```

Edit: try changing the value to "Source Code Pro". This works on my PC.

Comment: You should check the font name or spelling again.